# - (void)applicationWillTerminate:(UIApplication *)application is not calling when app removed from background

Tags: ios4, background

The method -(void)applicationWillTerminate:(UIApplication *)application is not calling when the app removed from background. Can any one tell me the reason for this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your application might be in the suspended state.  From the "iOS Application Programming Guide" ([link1](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/iphone/conceptual/iphoneosprogrammingguide/BackgroundExecution/BackgroundExecution.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH5-SW4))([link2](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/iphone/conceptual/iphoneosprogrammingguide/CoreApplication/CoreApplication.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH3-SW14)):

- "Most applications that enter the
  background state are moved to the
  suspended state shortly thereafter."
- "The applicationWillTerminate: method
  is not called if your application is
  currently suspended."
- "If your application is currently
  suspended, the system removes your
  application from memory without any
  notice."

You may want to use `applicationDidEnterBackground:` instead.  Or you could opt out of background execution entirely, but then your program would just end when a user presses the Home button.